# How to create a user with MangoPay API in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-4, sdk

After having installed the gem ( https://github.com/MangoPay/mangopay2-ruby-sdk ), and configured client id + passphrase, I would like to check that authentication is ok or simply create a user but I couldn't find how.

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController

 def index
  MangoPay::NaturalUser.create({
  Tag: 'test',
  Email: 'my@email.com',
  FirstName: 'John',
  LastName: 'Doe',
  Address: 'Here',
  Birthday: Date.parse('01-01-2000').to_time.to_i,
  Birthplace: 'Paris',
  Nationality: 'FR',
  CountryOfResidence: 'FR',
  Occupation: 'Worker',
  IncomeRange: 1
    })
 end
end
```

Create sandbox credentials
http://docs.mangopay.com/api-references/sandbox-credentials/

API Doc
http://docs.mangopay.com/api-references/users/

Comment: First question: after running bundle did you restart the server?

Comment: Hi Benjamin, thank you, you're right I did not. Now that I have restarted the server, I don't get the error but I am still looking for a way to check that  authentication is ok and manipulate the API (for example, how to create a user).

Comment: For this I can't help sorry, I know nothing about it.

Comment: You should edit your question to clarify the problem you have (taking out the `uninitialized constant` issue) so you have more chance to get help from someone that knows MangoPay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code I mentioned is ok for testing authentication and creating a user with MangoPay SDK. 
Just do not forget to restart the server like I did!